# Microsoft Excel 2010 Shared workbook - edit conflicts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, editing, sharing

We are using Microsoft Excel 2010 on Server NT.

We log onto the server using remote desktop on our local machines.

The excel file we are using has lists of clients, client details and trades that are needed on their jobs (we are builders)

My problem is that when I finish a job and delete it from the shared spreadsheet it will quite often delete a different line in someone elses sheet. If they add a comment to "Jones" that comment could turn up on "Smith"

Why is this happening and how do I stop it from happening?  I cannot trust that the data in the spreadsheet is correct.

Should I be using a different program?

Thanks in advance for your help

[edit list conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dhRK.jpg)

Comment: Excel 2010 is not yet optimised for parallel editing. You can use e.g. sharepoint, Excel online, Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use excel, but instead of opening the sheet normally we can instead share it using the build in functions of excel.

[This](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61) Link gives the full information.

Note that some features of excel do not function in the shared document, the link has the details.

The short hand is that you do the following:

- Open Your spreadsheet
- Click the review tab at the top
- In the Changes area, click share workbook
- Click allow changes by more than one person at the same time.
- Choose the options in the advanced tab to your preference.
- Save your worksheet.

The worksheet will now be able to merge changes between users, and in the event of conflicts, users will be informed of them and offered the chance to correct them.

To give you an alternative point of view, access is also an option. It requires a bit more work in the beginning, but in the long run is more resilient to multiple users than excel. You can create group of tables to manage customer records, order details etc. This way you can keep history of what has happened, plan what will happen and so forth.

You can then create forms to display this in a way that is convenient to you. The added benefit is that if you create the tables in one access database and the front end forms in another database, then multiple users can use it without worries about database corruption caused by multiple access.